# Function to find the MAX and its position on an array

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I have to find the max element and its position on an array(the position starts with 1)( if the array doesn't contain any elements I have to return position=0 and max=smallest negative number). I think that my code is ok (apart from setting the max to the lowest number possible, that I have doubt about) but I have no idea what I need to start my code with, like save the last thing stored in the registers. Also I can't compile it (probably because of the pseudo-instructions).

I have tried writing my program in c and then compiling to MIPS but it still wouldn't work.

```
MaxAndArg:
        li $v0, -2,147,483,648  # $v0(MAX) is the smallest negative number 
        li $v1, 0                # $v1(POSITION) starts from zero
        li $t3, 0                # $t3(i in a normal language) will be used to loop
        li $t4, 0               # $t4 will be used to show the position in the array

L2:         
            beq $t3, $a1, EXIT      # if (i = array size) goto EXIT

            sll $t4, $t4, 2         # $t4 = $t4 * 4
            add $a0, $t4, $a0      # $a0 = $a0 + $t4 (next element in the array)

            blt $v0, a0, L1      # if (max < a[j]) goto L1

            addi $t3, $t3, 1        # i++
            addi $t4, $t4, 1          # array_position++

            j L2

L1: 
        addi $v0, $a0, 0        # $v0 = $a0  
        addi $v1, $t3, 1        # $v1 = i + 1 (probably works)
        addi $t3, $t3, 1        # i++
        addi $t4, $t4, 1        # array_position++

            j L2

EXIT:       
         jr     $ra             #return
```

Comment: you probably have to **remove the commas in `-2,147,483,648`  to make it parse as a single number**.  The other option is to start with max = first element if the array is non-empty.  But since empty input is possible, you might as well start with the return value for that case.  `max(INT_MIN, x) == x` for *any* x, so it's a safe starting value.  It's either correct or will be replaced, this is totally standard.

Comment: Your code doesn't access memory at all.  There are no `lw` instructions, just a shift/add to calculate a pointer in `$a0` which you then don't dereference.  It's much much easier to just `addi $a0, $a0, 4` to increment your pointer, like C `ptr++`.

Comment: BTW, you left out the error messages you got from trying to compile this.  [edit] those in to make it a [mcve].  Probably just the number with commas and the missing `$` on `a0`, but people with the same problem as you are probably going to run into it while writing code for a completely different purpose.  The point of stack overflow is so future readers can search and find answers.  If your question doesn't make that possible, it's useless.

Comment: If I remove the commas is that an ok number to use or it could cause problems? What do I need to use the lw for? I will use your way for the pointer next time as it seems easier.

Comment: This one [link](https://visualmips.github.io/) gives me error in line 2 and this one [link](https://rivoire.cs.sonoma.edu/cs351/wemips/) does not recognise blt as a command.

Comment: I compiled it succesfully using qtspim but it doesn't do what it is supposed to do